# How to check the current commit id, a particular branch of a cloned repository is currently on from the terminal

Tags: git, github

I need to check the current commit id wrt a particular branch of a cloned repository from the terminal.

I need this to merge a commit of a particular branch(say branch 1) with another branch(say branch 2).

Fetching the current commit wrt branch2 would help me to be updated on whats my current position wrt this branch. I can thus go about merging accordingly.

**UPDATED**

I just want a "command" which would reflect the current commit id I am on for a specific branch. This would for e.g. help me find out if I have done a revert in the "same" branch to an older commit, I can check how many such commits I am behind by wrt the latest commit..

Thank you..

Comment: I've updated the question.. hope its more clear now..

Comment: The question is in the title..

Comment: Sorry, the question is still totally confused. Anyway, have you tried `gitk branch1...branch2`?

Comment: I have updated the question in the body and changed it appropriately in the title. Thanks..Hope its more clear now.. Please let me know what part of it isn't clear, before doing an upvote to close this question. That would be highly appreciated. Thanks..

Comment: It's still confused. The problem is "check commit with respect to something", which makes no sense. Commit is single point in history. It exists without respect to anything. So I guessed you want to see history relative to (and responded accordingly).

Comment: I just want a "command" which would reflect the current commit id I am on for a specific branch. This would for e.g. help me find out if I have done a revert in the "same" branch to an older commit, I can check how many such commits I am behind by..

Comment: I'm still confused, you want to give a command branch x and branch y.  What do you want the returned command to say.  I think your terminology is slightly off, so I believe it will help if you give us an example of what you want returned

Comment: Andy: The command should basically return the commit id at the least, a branch is currently on. This is wrt the currently "checked" out branch of a cloned repository.. Hope this makes it clear

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confused, but I guess you are looking for the `gitk` command. It will show you the revision tree starting from specified points.

```
gitk --all # Complete history starting from all refs
gitk ref1 # History leading to ref1
gitk ref1 ref2 # History leading to ref1 and ref2
gitk ref1 ^ref2 # History leading to ref1 since it diverged from ref2
gitk ref2..ref1 # Ditto
gitk ref1...ref2 # History of ref1 and ref2 since they diverged
```

oh, and in the `..` and `...` form, nothing is HEAD, so

```
gitk ..ref # What is in ref that I didn't merge to me yet
gitk ref.. # What I have that I didn't push to ref yet
gitk ...ref # What is my relation to ref
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, I don't really know much about gitk, trying to find my way to through this.. . +1 for gitk and how very useful it could be from the terminal..

Answer (score 1):

The [git show-branch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show-branch.html) command will describe the divergence of your branches. If you are on branch1, and branch2 has some unmerged commits, it will show them to you.

Comment: +1 for the informative command, would really be useful. Thanks..:)